# PHP Sql Server output parameter gives error when fetching datas for login

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am getting this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )
>   when I tried to fetch login details from the database. Please what could be the issue? Here are the codes for database connection and login syntax.

db.ini

```
host = DESKTOP-6VRJGMG
dbname = info
user = sa
pass = admin@12
/*type = mysql*/
```

dbcoonection

```
<?php
$db = parse_ini_file("../config/db.ini");

$user = $db['user'];
$pass = $db['pass'];
$dbname = $db['dbname'];
$host = $db['host'];
//$type = $db['type'];

$serverName = $host;
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$dbname,"UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

Login page

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uname'])
{
    header("Location: admin/index.php");
}
require_once 'cons.php';
 <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">
              <div id="error">
              <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        #catches user/password submitted by html form
                        $user = strip_tags($_POST['user_email']);
                        //$password = $_POST['password'];

                        #checks if the html form is filled
                        if(empty($_POST['user_email'])){
                            echo '<div class="alert-warning" id="alert_message">Enter your username to continue!</div>';
                        }else{

                        #searches for user and password in the database
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM fsusers WHERE username='$user'";
                        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  //$conn is your connection in 'connection.php'

                        #checks if the search was made
                        if($result == false){
                             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }

                        #checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
                        if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
                               echo '<div class="alert-warning" id="alert_message">Username not found.</div>';

                        }else{

                        #creates sessions
                            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
                               $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['username'];
                               $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['fullname'];



                            }
                        #redirects user if credential is valid
                            header("refresh:1;pupdate?dir='".$_SESSION['uname']."'"); //redirect user after 2 secs
                        }
                        }
                        }

?>
        <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
        </div>
                <div class="body bg-gray">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                         <span id="check">


                         </span>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"/> Remember me
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <div class="footer">    
                <div align="center">                                                           
                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" id="btn-login"  value="Confirm">

                   </div> 

                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: I would guess that the invalid parameter is `$conn` given that the SQL seems ok (except for the SQL Injection issues). Check to see whether the values from the ini file were fetched correctly and if the connection was actually created.

Comment: You're right the path to the connection was not found...Working now. Thanks again!